# How to implement custom cell selection behavior with button for UITableViewController?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitableview

I'm trying to replace standard table cell selection behavior with a button-press behavior. The result should be same - to push `detailViewController` on top and to present some detail info. The cell view is loaded from a separate xib file. So, I need to put a button in that cell xib and use that button for opening detail VC in table VC. I have placed the button view in cell xib, and disabled cell selection in table VC viewDidLoad, but now, I'm not sure how to handle that button press, where to place the button press code or what delegate method to use because `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is not respoding (cos I disabled it). Any suggestions?

*UPDATE:* I need to get some info from cell (section, index) on button press in order to initialize the data for detail VC. Also, should note, that there will be several buttons in each cell.

*UPDATE2:* I'm using rows with sections, so on button press I need to pass both section and row numbers that corresponds to cell where the button was pressed.

*UPDATE3:* I have tried to use unique tags for identifying cells but it looks like it's not the solution because I'm getting problems with cell reusing. The first 9 rows are created and relevant tag number are set to them. But then every row from 10 is reused from the queue, so I get the same 9 view with their tags. For example, 10th row pops me the first row button from the queue with the tag 1, 11th - second row button with tag 2 and so on. I mean, the whole dequeue cells means that it doesn't matter how much rows do you have in table, there will be reused 9 cell views for all of the table rows. That means I cannot assign unique tags for the cells because the cell views are not unique for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestions with tags didn't worked out because of a reason described in UPDATE3. However, I did succeed by calling "magic" indexPathForRowAtPoint: method. So the solutions is:

1) attach custom method for button press in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
// I have already created/loaded and got a handler to my button btn 
// here comes attaching
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(openDetailViewController:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

2) Define custom method:

```
-(void)openDetailViewController:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event{

  NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
  UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
  CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:currentTouchPosition];
  // do my stuff
}
```

So, when the button gets pressed my method gets called, passing some additional parameter like event. By calling "allTouches" and "anyObject" I'm getting the touch. Then, I'm retrieving CGPoint from that touch, then passing that point to "indexPathForRowAtPoint" that returns desired indexPath with section and row number. Cool :)

Answer (score 1):

If i got u r question right then this will be solution

```
[cell.yourButton addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
//you can use tag property of button
    NSUInteger tag=indexPath.row+1;
    cell.yourButton.tag=tag;
```

this code should be in

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

& you write action as

```
-(IBAction)myAction:(id)sender{
     UIButton *but=(UIButton *)sender;
     NSLog(@"Tag-%d",but.tag);
     NSUInteger index=but.tag-1;  
  //using tag you will come to know which button is pressed ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should add "myAction" method to all those buttons in cells. However, on every button press I need to know what cell (indexPath.section and row numbers) button was pressed. The sender parameter of button-press method only passes some info about the button. One solution would be to set unique tag for every button but I need to set two number (section and row number) but the tag is a place to set only one number. Certainly, I could use some smart coding algorythmn to bundle section and row number into one tag number, but maybe there are other options...??

Comment: Set tag = a*section + row. a is enough large number to avoid same tag.

Comment: I wanted to suggest setting tags to buttons but I see a problem: how do you get reference to that buttons? I think via : `[cell viewForTag:<tag>];`. Then you will broke reusing this cells.

Comment: @ChangUZ: thanks, that definitely the solution. But you know what, I have even more complicated problem, cos I'm showing one-cell-in-row in portrait mode, and two-cells-in-row in landscape mode :) For landscap I guess need to use two formulas: for left btn tag = (a*section + row) and for right btn tag = (a*section + row) + 1

Comment: Hm, I'm getting problems with cell reusing. The first 9 rows are created and relevant tag number are set to them. But then every row from 10 is reused from the queue, so I get the same 9 view with their tags. For example, 10th row pops me the first row button from the queue with the tag 1, 11th - second row button with tag 2 and so on. I mean, the whole dequeue cells means that it doesn't matter how much rows do you have in table, there will be reused 9 cell views for all of the table rows. That means I cannot assign unique tags for the cells because the cell views are not unique for each row

Comment: Plz post code written in cellForRowAtIndexPath method...because in my case it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the help, posted achieved solution above. As for tags, cells as views are reused, that means there will be created only that cell number that is required to cover the screen, I mean, will be alloc'ed&init'ed only several cell views (with default row height it will be 9 cell objects in iphone). As user scrolls down the table, the most top cell view objects will be reused for  showing the most bottom cells. Only the data will be changed when assigning in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Tag property belongs to view. Therefore cell objects are reused it's impossible to have unique tags for cells